# db:migrate fails in Emacs shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

When I rake my db in emacs, it fails– although it works fine in terminal. The error is related specifically to an environment variable that emacs doesn't seem to be picking up on. What is the best way to resolve this in .emacs? Do I need to source my profile every time I start emacs?

Answer (score 0):

Which emacs shell are you using?  There are a few different types which are good for different cases.  I recently read this article which you may find informative: http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/11/01/running-shells-in-emacs-overview/

I suggest trying simply `M-x shell` which will simply run your default shell in emacs (usually bash).

Comment: im using bash, and invoking it by M-x shell. Is it common that emacs does not pick up on everything in .profile?